# What language did Gaius Julius Caesar speak with Cleopatra?

Tags: ancient-rome, language, egypt, latin-language

What language did Gaius Julius Caesar (GJC) speak with Cleopatra?

My thoughts:

GJC spoke Latin.

Cleopatra spoke many languages, including Arabic, Aramaic, Hebrew, Egyptian, Greek.

Or did they need a translator?

My preliminary research consisted of an effort to make a list of languages they both spoke and look for the common ones

Comment: What has your preliminary [research shown](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)?

Comment: My preliminary research consisted of an effort to make a list of languages they both spoke and look for the common ones.

Comment: At that time, Greek was the most common language in the Roman empire.

Comment: that wasn't very good preliminary research if you didn't find that Caesar almost certainly spoke multiple languages, Greek among them, and if it showed Cleopatra speaking Arabic which may not even have existed outside of some remote tribes in Arabia.

Comment: @jwenting Arabic is a semitic language, alongside Hebrew, Aramaic, Phoenician and Ethiopian languages, which were certainly widely spoken in the North Africa. It was certainly not as widespread in North Africa as it would be some 7-8 centuries later, but not as rare as your post comment to imply.

Comment: @jwenting Wikipedia states: *In contrast, Cleopatra could speak multiple languages by adulthood and was the first Ptolemaic ruler to learn the Egyptian language. Plutarch implies that she also spoke Ethiopian, the language of the "Troglodytes", Hebrew (or Aramaic), **Arabic**, the Syrian language (perhaps Syriac), Median, and Parthian, and she could apparently also speak Latin, although her Roman contemporaries would have preferred to speak with her in her native Koine Greek.* [Cleopatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra)

Comment: The same way English is the current lingua franca, and before that it was French and before that it was Latin, Greek was the lingua franca back then as Lars' answer explains. So, your question is similar to *"What language did Pilate speak with Jesus?"*, some 70 years after Caesar and Cleopatra... Most probably Greek.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado How is Lars wrong?

When English is your lingua franca, what happened to Spanish? I've heard it said not only that more of us see Spanish as their first tongue… so what? - but also that many more speak Spanish as a second, third or "extra" language - which is what lingua franca boils down to.

Roughly when did English over-take French and for roughly how long before that did French reign?

That Latin was - and remains - the lingua franca of Christian scholars says what about anyone else?

What can you say from knowledge, as opposed to guesswork, however well inspired?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I didn't say Lars is wrong, quite the opposite, I'm saying he's correct.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sorry; I tripped over your comma and misread your Post as not "Greek was the lingua franca back then as Lars' answer explains" but rather the whole shebang, "The same way English is the current lingua franca, and before that it was French and before that it was Latin, Greek was the lingua franca back then as Lars' answer explains."

Answer (score 87):

**Most likely Greek.** This is the only language which we know they definitely had in common, and both were highly proficient in it.

High-born Romans learnt Greek and [Julius Caesar was no exception](https://www.ushistory.org/civ/6b.asp#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%201st%20century,most%20patricians%20at%20the%20time.):

> According to the 1st century C.E. Roman historian Suetonius, Julius
> Caesar spoke mainly Greek and not Latin, as was the case with most
> patricians at the time.

Richard A. Billows, Professor of Greek and Roman History at Columbia
University in New York, elaborates on Caesar's education:

> The formal side of his education consisted of being taught to read and
> write both Latin and Greek, given a grounding in the classic poets of
> Rome (Ennius, Naevius, Terence and others) and Greece (Homer, some of
> the lyric poets, the Athenian dramatists and others), and then taught
> a smattering of Greek philosophy, but above all the art of rhetoric.

*Source: Richard A. Billows, '[Julius Caesar: The Colossus of Rome](https://archive.org/details/julius-caesar-the-colossus-o)' (2009)*

Cleopatra, being of the [Ptolemaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemaic_Kingdom) dynasty of Egypt, [spoke Greek](https://www.reference.com/history/nine-languages-did-cleopatra-speak-7a72a4afbe5424ab):

> Most historians agree that Cleopatra did not speak Latin and that she
> spoke Greek, which was her native language. The historian Plutarch was
> not convinced that she actually did speak Egyptian, and many modern
> scholars agree with him. Some languages that she may have spoken were
> Persian, Syrian and Arabic. However, there is no true historical proof
> that she spoke anything other than Greek.

Plutarch also mentions Ethiopian, [Trogodyte](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1794358), [Hebraioi](https://johnstott.org/bible_studies/23-jan-2018/), Parthian and others not specified. One of the latter may have been Latin but we can only speculate on that as,

> Plutarch is our only ancient source for Cleopatra’s knowledge of these
> languages. Note that Latin is not included in the list. It is possible
> that Latin was one of the many other languages with which Plutarch
> credits Cleopatra, but Julius Caesar and Mark Antony spoke Greek, so
> communication would not have been a problem.

*Source: Prudence J. Jones, 'Cleopatra: a Sourcebook' (2006)*

[Duane W. Roller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duane_W._Roller), Professor of Classics, is more [open to the idea that Cleopatra spoke Latin](https://archive.org/details/cleopatrabiograp00roll_0) but nonetheless concurs that she would have spoken Greek with Julius Caesar and other Romans.

---

**A Note on Plutarch's use of Arabic**

Although somewhat off-topic in relation to the question, the mention of Arabic has generated a fair amount of discussion in the comments. This is evident in the academic literature:

> The meaning of the term ‘Arab’ in antiquity has been hotly debated for
> many decades. One reason for this has been the search for a single
> definition which could be applied to all the numerous references to
> ‘Arabs’ and ‘Arabias’ in the ancient sources. As noted above, the vast
> majority of these sources were written by authors looking at the
> ancient Near East from the outside.

*Source: G. Fisher (ed), '[Arabs and Empires before Islam](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199654529.001.0001/acprof-9780199654529)' (2015)*

Plutarch's reference probably relates to one of the languages spoken on Arabian peninsula, possibly [Nabataean Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabataean_Arabic). [Modern scholarship postulates](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199654529.001.0001/acprof-9780199654529) that the spoken form probably predates the written form by several centuries, perhaps as early as the 4th century BC. Consequently, Arab speakers

> used other languages for writing, principally Nabataean Aramaic in the
> north of the Peninsula, and Sabaʾic in the south. Thus an Arabic
> speaker would either learn the language and script of Aramaic or
> Sabaic in order to be able to write, or employ someone to write, in
> these languages for him/her.

*Source: Fisher*

On the importance of Nabataea to Egypt,

> Across the Red Sea was the Arabian peninsula. Although only small
> parts of it were ever under Ptolemaic control, this region was a vital
> part of the Ptolemaic kingdom’s economy. The great Nabataean trading
> center of Petra began to flourish in the late fourth century b.c., and
> a certain Anaxikrates explored the Red Sea for Alexander, reaching the
> wealthy aromatics-producing regions at its southern end. By the third
> century b.c. the trade route from Petra to these districts was well
> known, and frankincense and myrrh, the two most famous aromatics, were
> exported to processing factories in Alexandria. Knowing the Arabian
> language may have assisted Cleopatra in diplomatic and mercantile
> negotiations, and she may have acquired some Arabian territory in the
> 30s b.c.

*Source: Billows*

Comment: Arabic? I had thought that Arabic was not widely spoken outside the Arabian peninsula, and certainly not as a prestige language until after the rise of Islam.

Comment: @scytale This comes from Plutarch and should be taken with a pinch of salt.

Comment: But anyway, Plutarch is still much older than the rise of Islam, provided that the mention is not a later interpolation.

Comment: @scytale Arabic afaik was indeed not spoken anywhere except by some tribes in Arabia. It's unlikely Cleopatra had much if any contact with those, and would likely have demanded they speak her language rather than the other way around.

Comment: Some forms of Arabic were likely spoken in the Syrian desert as far North as Palmyra, even in antiquity. That said, Cleopatra speaking it seems doubtful whatever Plutarch says. The nearest polity speaking any form of Arabic would be the Nabataeans, and they seem to have preferred Aramaic for official purposes, so speaking Arabic would have been little advantage to diplomacy with them. There were also likely lots of Arabic-speaking traders on the Red Sea, but that would be more relevant to a merchant than a monarch

Comment: Throughout "Arabic" should be understood as languages more closely related to Old Arabic than to any other surviving language, and not to imply identity with or being ancestral to Old Arabic

Comment: tbh, Phoenician-Punic would seem more plausible than Arabic, although still not very likely

Comment: Presumably for the Greeks "Arabic" encompassed North and South Arabian languages. South Arabian is very well attested in inscriptions long before the time of Cleopatra and there is good evidence for trade relations between Egypt and South Arabia (Yemen) along the Red Sea.

Comment: @LarsBosteen More than a pinch of salt - even Old Arabic's oldest known writings didn't appear until the 1st century CE, long after Caesar and Cleopatra were dead.  Aramaic would be believable.  It's probably a mistranslation. Even Plutarch was dead before Old Arabic really started to appear.

Comment: @J... Have you heard of Ancient South Arabian?

Comment: @fdb Yes, and it's a good guess.  The point was merely that, in the English of today, *"Arabic"* is perhaps the wrong word, or at least a confusing word, to have chosen for the translation.  Old South Arabian is a pretty distant relation, and a murky one at that.

Comment: @Jan When your preliminary research consisted of an effort to make a list of languages they both spoke, what did JC list? You suggest "GJC spoke Latin". That's tantamount to suggesting he spoke only Latin. Was that your intent?

It might be true, but where's your evidence?

Answer (score 0):

Julius Caesar most likely spoke Latin and Greek to Cleopatra-(with a greater emphasis on the latter).

The Greek language was still widely spoken among the Aristocrats and Patricians throughout much of the Mediterranean and Middle Eastern regions-(including, Egypt).  Cleopatra herself, was either of Greek or Greco-Egyptian ethnic origin and so for her, the Greek language would have been her "mother tongue".

In the case of Julius Caesar, he was-(albeit for a short while), the most Patrician of Patricians in Roman society whereby the Greek language was the preferred language among the sophisticates.

When adding the native tongue of Cleopatra, coupled with the preferred language of the Patricians-(such as Julius Caesar), Greek-(and not Latin), would have been the primary form of communication between Caesar and Cleopatra.

(To the best of my knowledge, I don't believe Julius Caesar spoke a word of Egyptian, though it is very likely that Cleopatra, was probably fluent in Egyptian).